# How to describe response in swagger with different properties?

Tags: node.js, swagger, nestjs, nestjs-swagger

I return object with different properties, like this

```
export class ProductsDto {
  [product: string]: ProductDto
}

export class ProductDto {
  @ApiResponseProperty()
  id: number;

  @ApiResponseProperty()
  price: number;
}
```

But, I don't see structure in swagger?